# Determining child counts of hierarchical paths

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table consisting of the following columns:

```
child_count | path
------------+-----
            | /
            | /a
            | /a/a
            | /a/b
            | /a/b/c
            | /b
```

Presently, only the path column has data.  I would like to know of an SQL (preferably PostgreSQL) query that would be able to determine the child count of each path as follows:

```
child_count | path
------------+-----
2           | /
2           | /a
0           | /a/a
1           | /a/b
0           | /a/b/c
0           | /b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andomar beat me while I was editing, but I'll post my solution anyway as it uses some PostgreSQL specific stuff.

```
with path_elements as (
  select path, array_length(string_to_array(path, '/'),1) as element_count
  from path_table
)
select parent_path, count(child_path) 
from (
  select p.path as parent_path,
         c.path as child_path
  from path_elements p
    left join path_elements c 
              on p.element_count + 1 = c.element_count 
             and substring(c.path, 1, length(p.path)) = p.path
) t
group by parent_path
order by parent_path;
```

Comment: I chose this as the answer as it is in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could count the depth of the path with:

```
len(path) - len(replace(path,'/',''))
```

Then children have one more depth than their parents, and children's path starts with the parent path:

```
on      children.depth = parents.depth + 1
        and substring(children.path, 1, len(parents.path)) = parents.path
```

Putting this together (for SQL Server, but should work on Postgres with minor changes):

```
;with depth as 
        (
select  depth = case when path = '/' then 0 
                     else len(path) - len(replace(path,'/','')) 
                end
,       path
from    YourTable
        )
select  COUNT(children.path) as child_count
,       parents.path
from    depth parents
left join
        depth children
on      children.depth = parents.depth + 1
        and substring(children.path, 1, len(parents.path)) = parents.path
group by    
        parents.path
```

This prints:

```
child_count path                
----------- --------------------
2           /                   
2           /a                  
0           /a/a                
1           /a/b                
0           /a/b/c              
0           /b
```

Test data:

```
if OBJECT_ID('YourTable') is not null
    drop table YourTable
create table YourTable (child_count int, path varchar(max))
insert YourTable (path) values
('/'),
('/a'),
('/a/a'),
('/a/b'),
('/a/b/c'),
('/b')
```

Comment: Off topic but out of curiosity because I see this so often: why are CTEs in SQL Server always **prefixed** with a semicolon? A semicolon normally *terminates* a statement? It's always a SQL Server solution where I see a semicolon at the start of the statement (and as far as I can tell, this is not required at all)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: In SQL Server, it's optional and unusual to end lines with a semicolon.  But it is required on the line preceding a `with` statement, and if you omit it, you get a confuzzled error message that points you in the wrong direction.  To avoid this situation, most people have adopted the habit of prefixing `with` with a semicolon.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the explanation. I have never used a semicolon in front of a CTE in SQL and never got an error either. And I always use a semicolon to terminate my statements. But then I don't use the Microsoft tools to run my SQL...